# Links de icones html/css

Tags: html, css

não consegui me expressar muito bem no titulo, porem é o seguinte, verificando o codigo fonte de alguns sites me deparei com codigos que nao entendo como funciona...segue o exemplo

```html
<tag class='setas'>seta_pra_baixo</tag>
```

, bem queria entender como é feito essa linkagem, pois o desenvolvedor coloca dentro da tag uma informação que puxa a imagem que ele deseja, alguem pode me explicar isso, e da um exemplo do codigo css..

Comment: Tem um exemplo de onde viu isso? O CSS não consegue pegar o que há dentro da tag e fazer um condicional para, a partir daquele conteúdo, renderizar um ícone. Talvez esteja falando de *font icons* (como por exemplo o [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#basic)) onde o ícone é definido pela classe, não pelo conteúdo da tag. Ficaria mais claro se você desse um exemplo...

Comment: Renan, por isso minha dúvida olha um trecho do codigo do site que vi, <i class="material-icons right">keyboard_arrow_down</i>, nesse codigo ele mostra icone de uma seta pra baixo posicionado a direita, da pra percerber que o icone e o posicionamento é pego pela class, agora a imagem a ser selecionada é escolhida pelo conteúdo que esta dentro da tag, tanto que o "keyboard_arrow_down" nao é exibido na pagina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja se referindo à utilização de Fontes Web de Ícones, implementadas com CSS.

Basicamente você tem que incluir o código CSS para a Fonte Web, que irá incluir os arquivos da fonte.

A formatação do HTML irá depender do distribuidor da fonte que for utilizar.

Há diversas opções, seguem algumas gratuitas disponíveis:

- [IconMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select/font)
- [Fontello](http://fontello.com/)
- [Google Material Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/)

**UPDATE: Como funciona?**

Os arquivos de fonte são compilados com um índice para cada desenho de caracter.

Por exemplo: a fonte **ARIAL** tem o índice 'a' para o desenho da letra 'a'.

No caso de ícones, é a mesma coisa, só que o índice para o desenho é algo mais intuitivo como por exemplo: `arrow_upward`, que é o índice para o desenho do ícone **"SETA PARA CIMA"**.

**Nota:** Pode haver mais de um índice para um mesmo desenho/caracter em uma fonte. (veja no exemplo do trecho de código abaixo)

No exemplo abaixo (com Google Material Icons):

- a fonte web criada (`@font-face`) a fonte apontando para o(s) seu(s) respectivo(s) arquivos(s) de fonte.
- a classe `material-icons` basicamente informa qual a fonte que vai ser utilizada e o RESET das configurações desta fonte (tamanho, margem, bordas, decoration, etc.).

Exemplo de CSS de RESET da fonte e da fonte:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  @include icone_reset();
}
@mixin icone_reset(){
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.2em;  /* Preferred icon size */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Veja que no trecho de código abaixo, utilizando o **Google Material Icons**, utilizei:

- um "índice" existente para o desenho "Telefone de contato";
- um "índice" existente para o desenho "Seta para cima";
- os dois "índices" acima em uma única Tag.
- um "índice" inválido (que não vai retornar nada).

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

Índice existente:
<i class="material-icons">contact_phone</i>
<br/><br/>
Índice existente:
<i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>
<br/><br/>
Dois índices existentes (dois desenhos em uma só tag: equivale a um texto com duas letras):
<i class="material-icons">contact_phonearrow_upward</i>
<br/><br/>
Um índice inexistente (não retorna nada):
<i class="material-icons">abc</i>
<br/><br/>
Índice existente (outro índice para o mesmo desenho "Seta para cima":
<i class="material-icons">&#xE5D8;</i>
```

Caso queira criar seu próprio arquivo de fontes, dê uma olhada neste tutorial (em inglês): [How to turn your icons into a web font](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/)

Comment: Obrigado Alan, era isso mesmo que queria entender, agora deixa eu lhe perguntar, tem alguma forma de eu mesmo fazer isso sem utilizar terceiros, eu mesmo criar meu css e fazer essa linkagem de indice ou é muito complexo? gostei da forma pois agiliza bastante o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Sim, mas você vai ter que criar/possuir todos os SVGs.... Dê uma olhada neste link  http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/